# Javascript onclick() show and onclick() hide

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to make a function with onclick where if I press the div the content should be displayed. If I click on that content it will give me the "starting"-form.

Let me show you the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">click</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementById("demo");
var info = "This is the information for the user.";     
var status = true;

if(status){
     div.onclick = function() { div.innerHTML = info };
     status=false;
}   
   else {
      div.onclick = function() { div.innerHTML = "click" };
      status=true;
   }
```

So I made a variable status that checks what is being shown.
I hope i could express myself good enough. :)

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It only works once. The second time I click on it nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if statement is not going to magically run again. You need to do the check inside the click. Do not try to bind separate click events.

```js
(function () {
  var div = document.getElementById("demo");
  var info = "This is the information for the user.";
  var status = false;
  div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    status = !status;
    div.innerHTML = status ? info : "click";
  });
}());
```

```html
<div id="demo">click</div>
```

Comment: Even if i click on the div  again? What I intended to do was, that if i click on it, it shows me the "information". When I click on it again now, it should show me the "click".

Comment: Which is what that code I posted above should do... Your code will not bind the events when the status changes. Once the code runs it is done, it does not go back and re run it.

Comment: Oh perfect, that was my problem! I thought it can be done over and over again. Thank you. :)

Comment: That code you posted works just like i want it.
Thank you very much.

Edit: 
So I should learn more over EventListener.